# How do I take some RAM and use it towards Dedicated video memory for my Nvidia graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card

I have a Nividia  GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 graphics card (so it's quite old), it only gets 64MB  of dedicated memory by default.

I went into the bios and see if I can increase it, but it wouldn't let me. However, from the Nividia control panel I see I have up to 1071MB of total available graphics memory.

I'm not sure what that means and I'm not sure how I can harness this memory and use some RAM for my graphics card. Can someone explain if this is possible and if so, how?

Comment: It's important to note that dedicating more memory isn't likely to improve performance. VRAM is used for texture storage

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can change the amount of dedicated memory, as the dedicated memory is the physical memory on the device itself, on some motherboard/GPU combinations (onboard devices mostly, with little to no dedicated memory) its possible to allocate more or less shared memory to the GPU, an option for that would typically be found in the driver options (under advanced settings I believe, correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: This is essentially correct. The "dedicated memory" is what is physically on the card. The Nvidia drivers should make use of available system memory when it is available and it can make use of it.